# Python CSV delimiter

Tags: python, export-to-csv

im trying to write a csv file where all the values are in different cells. my code right now:

```
fieldnames = ['name', 'deviceId', 'lastSync', 'type']

filename = "data.csv"
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for data in dixtt:
        print([data['name'], data['deviceId'], data['lastSync'], data['type']])
```

prefered output (the data output will be added once this problem is solved):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtOq6.png)

what im getting:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qUS6.png)

i want all the data values in different cells (see picture examples). ive tried changing the settings in excel through data -> text to columns and setting the delimiter there but that didnt work

Comment: From your image, it looks like you have a list of words separated by commas, which is exactly what a csv file is: you set your delimiter to ",". Are you sure that you set the delimiter to comma in Exel?

Comment: Its probably not a problem with your script. PLease look up excel not reading .csv properly. https://satsuite.collegeboard.org/help-center/how-do-i-open-csv-file-microsoft-excel-without-changing-column-formatting

Comment: @XaC thats correct. if you look at my first line of code thats the data and the 4th line has the delimiter already and it still gives me that output

Comment: set your excel delimiter to comma

Comment: or change to `delimiter=";"` which is probably the setting in excel

Answer (score 0):

Your csv is fine, you just need to tell Excel to format the data properly.

Follow this steps:

- Select the column "A"
- Go in "Data" and click "Text to column"
- Select "delimited"
- Select "comma"